# Will Wordpress be able to maintain a multi-user login website?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, content-management-system

I am making a website for my college in which students will have to register and then can log-in and have their own profile. This would mean maintaining database with multiple usernames, passwords and other data. Students would be able to form groups, communities and ask questions to others.

How can Wordpress be useful in developing a website like this? Are there other good WP tutorials?

I have already installed WP and am going through its [Lessons](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Lessons), but it seems to be all about one user (admin) writing his own blog and controlling the posts/comments of others. The other users don't seem to be logged in. (Maybe I missed the lesson on multi-user login as I have just started a day back).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Default capabilities

Wordpress has [multi-user support built-in.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) You can add as many accounts to your site as you wish. There are different types of accounts, differing in what a user can do:

> - Super Admin - Someone with access to the blog network
>     administration features controlling the entire network (See Create a
>     Network).
> - Administrator - Somebody who has access to all the
>     administration features
> - Editor - Somebody who can publish and
>     manage posts and pages as well as manage other users' posts, etc.
> - Author - Somebody who can publish and manage their own posts
> - Contributor - Somebody who can write and manage their posts but not
>     publish them
> - Subscriber - Somebody who can only manage their
>     profile

You don't need to set up all users manually, but allow people to sign up themselves, limited to a certain account type (e.g. let them only create subscriber accounts with limited access).

#### Plugin: Buddypress

There the [Buddypress Plugin](http://buddypress.org/) for Wordpress. It extends Wordpress to be more like a social network.

> What can I use BuddyPress for?
>
> BuddyPress is built to bring people together. It works well to enable
>   people with similar interests to connect and communicate. Some of the
>   fantastic uses might be:
>
> - A campus wide social network for your university, school or college.
> - An internal communication tool for your company.
> - A niche social network for your interest topic.
> - A focused social network for your new product.

This sounds like a good way to go if you're just getting started with Wordpress development.

Comment: Thanks... One more thing: For SignUp and SignIn functionality, do I have to write code for forms and the corresponding database tables, or some plug-in will take care of that?

Comment: For both solutions, there's no need for you to write any code or add your own tables just to get it working. There are configuration options to enable user registration.

Comment: Thanks...it works except the account activation email after registration is not being delivered. I am working from localhost. What changes do I need to make for localhost? and also when I host the site and the database on a remote server?